Configuring 2 UVC Gadgets with UDC controller
We are testing the use-case of delivering 2 UVC streams from the qcomm SoC. Should the hardware allow this feature? I have enabled 2 gadgets, but when I activate the second one, I get resource busy error at the UDC Controller. But the first one is activated.
I can succesfully stream one UVC gadget. I can create two gadgets, but only one could be activated in parallel.
Would this use-case be supported from the UVC standard, or it it limited per Hardware-driver binded to USB?
Thank you!
